# optimize this ruby code

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization

So this code will count the total number of pairs of numbers whose difference is K. it is naive method and I need to optimize it. suggestions?

```
test = $stdin.readlines 

input = test[0].split(" ")

numbers = test[1].split(" ")

N = input[0]
K = input[1]

count = 0

for i in numbers
   current = i.to_i
   numbers.shift
   for j in numbers
       difference = (j.to_i - current).abs
       if (difference == K)
           count += 1
       end
   end
end

puts count
```

Comment: Is `N` even useful? If there is another part of the code we can't see, could you remove the parts we don't need? XD

Comment: sorry N is the number of numbers

Comment: `numbers.shift`, doesn't it make the loops innacurate? If you have [1,2,3,4], wouldn't `i` take only 1 and 3 as values?

Comment: eh? if numbers is [1,2,3,4] then j gets [2,3,4]

Comment: `j`, on the first loop yes, but `i`? wouldn't it take 1 then, going to the new second index, gets 3 as a value, missing 2?

Comment: i don't think it works like that

Comment: Can you try running this small script? `arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` `for i in arr` `puts i` `arr.shift` `end`

Comment: This task is a codility test (codility.com).  I don't remember if it is one of the demos or if it was in a challenge I was given.

Comment: this isn't from codility but it is a common test/interview question so I wanted to see how to improve my answer

Comment: er if it is codility, i didn't know about it from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would have been nice for you to give some examples of input and output, but I think this is correct.

```
require 'set'

def count_diff(numbers, difference)
  set = Set.new numbers
  set.inject 0 do |count, num|
    set.include?(num+difference) ? count+1 : count
  end
end


difference  =  gets.split[1].to_i
numbers     =  gets.split.map { |num| num.to_i }

puts count_diff(numbers, difference)
```

Answer (score 3):

Untested, hopefully actual Ruby code

Documentation for Set: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/classes/Set.html

```
require 'set'
numbers_set = Set.new
npairs = 0

numbers.each do |number|
     if numbers_set.include?(number + K)
         npairs += 1
     end
     if numbers_set.include?(number - K)
         npairs += 1
     end
     numbers_set.add(number)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone deleted his post, or his post was deleted... He had the best solution, here it is :

```
test = $stdin.readlines
input = test[0].split(" ")
numbers = test[1].split(" ")
K = input[1]
count = 0
numbers.combination(2){|couple| couple.inject(:-).abs == K ? count++}
puts count
```

You don't even need N.

Comment: this was slower then mine thats why he delete it

Comment: If I am right about the lost data (mentioned in comments of the question), then you are running at least two times too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Ruby so I'll just give you the big idea:

1. Get the list
2. Keep a boolean array (call it `arr`), marking off numbers as true if the number exists in the list
3. Loop through the list and see if `arr[num-K]` and/or `arr[num+K]` is true where `num` is a number in your list

This uses up quite a bit of memory though so another method is to do the following:

1. Keep a hash map from an integer `n` to an integer `count`
2. Go through your list, adding `num+K` and `num-K` to the hash map, incrementing `count` accordingly
3. Go through your list and see if `num` is in the hash map. If it is, increment your counter by `count`